# Twig for loop for arrays with keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, twig

I use Twig and I have an array with keys like this:

```
array[1] = "alpha"
array[2] = "bravo"
array[3] = "charlie"
array[8] = "delta"
array[9] = "echo"
```

And I would like to get the key `(1,2,3,8,9)` and the content `(alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo)` in a loop to get all value of this array.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try searching PHP loops? Use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Comment: It's not in PHP it's in Twig in the template file!

Comment: Fair enough. Did you try searching for TWIG loops? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Answer (score 383, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
{% for key,value in array_path %}
    Key : {{ key }}
    Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Here's a link to the official docs: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values

Answer (score 65):

There's this example in the SensioLab page on the `for` tag:

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
    {% for key, user in users %}
        <li>{{ key }}: {{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys

Comment: This example doesn't iterate over the array keys, see the ones above

Answer (score 34):

These are extended operations (e.g., sort, reverse) for one dimensional and two dimensional arrays in Twig framework:

### 1D Array

#### Without Key Sort and Reverse

```
{% for key, value in array_one_dimension %}
    <div>{{ key }}</div>
    <div>{{ value }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort

```
{% for key, value in array_one_dimension|keys|sort %}
    <div>{{ key }}</div>
    <div>{{ value }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort and Reverse

```
{% for key, value in array_one_dimension|keys|sort|reverse %}
    <div>{{ key }}</div>
    <div>{{ value }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

### 2D Arrays

#### Without Key Sort and Reverse

```
{% for key_a, value_a in array_two_dimension %}
    {% for key_b, value_b in array_two_dimension[key_a] %}
        <div>{{ key_b }}</div>
        <div>{{ value_b }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort on Outer Array

```
{% for key_a, value_a in array_two_dimension|keys|sort %}
    {% for key_b, value_b in array_two_dimension[key_a] %}
        <div>{{ key_b }}</div>
        <div>{{ value_b }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort on Both Outer and Inner Arrays

```
{% for key_a, value_a in array_two_dimension|keys|sort %}
    {% for key_b, value_b in array_two_dimension[key_a]|keys|sort %}
        <div>{{ key_b }}</div>
        <div>{{ value_b }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort on Outer Array & Key Sort and Reverse on Inner Array

```
{% for key_a, value_a in array_two_dimension|keys|sort %}
    {% for key_b, value_b in array_two_dimension[key_a]|keys|sort|reverse %}
        <div>{{ key_b }}</div>
        <div>{{ value_b }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort and Reverse on Outer Array & Key Sort on Inner Array

```
{% for key_a, value_a in array_two_dimension|keys|sort|reverse %}
    {% for key_b, value_b in array_two_dimension[key_a]|keys|sort %}
        <div>{{ key_b }}</div>
        <div>{{ value_b }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

#### Key Sort and Reverse on Both Outer and Inner Array

```
{% for key_a, value_a in array_two_dimension|keys|sort|reverse %}
    {% for key_b, value_b in array_two_dimension[key_a]|keys|sort|reverse %}
        <div>{{ key_b }}</div>
        <div>{{ value_b }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to do the "Iterating over Keys and Values"

As the doc [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) says, just add "|keys" in the variable you want and it will magically happen.

```
{% for key, user in users %}
    <li>{{ key }}: {{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

It never hurts to search before asking :)

Comment: You've not shown an example of using "|keys" in your answer.

Comment: I give you 10 because you have 308 points, but you answer "It never hurts to search before asking" sucks, so I take it out