# Index value in for loop with Twig

Tags: twig

I'd like to store the iteration value to use in `data-target` so it would be `#question0`, `#quesion1`, `#question2` and so on...

I tried using `{{item.id}}` but this didn't work.

```
{% for item in post.get_field('qanda') %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle question-toggle collapsed"
    data-parent="#faqAccordion" data-target="#question{{item.id}}"
    data-toggle="collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="ing">Q:
        {{item.question}}</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="question{{item.id}}" style=
    "height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{item.answer}}
        </div>
    </div>{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Resolved using answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299202/twig-for-loop-and-array-with-key

Will post full Answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the variable loop.index0 (for zero based indexing).

```
data-target="#question{{loop.index0}}"
```

should do what you want. See the [for loop documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) for more info for more information.