# Get index # of array in twig

Tags: php, twig

Trying to output the index # of an array in twig, having trouble finding it in the docs.  Anyone know how to get it?

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["testimonial"]=>
    string(18) "Derby Heist Test 1"
    ["author"]=>
    string(6) "test 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["testimonial"]=>
    string(18) "Derby Heist Test 2"
    ["author"]=>
    string(6) "test 2"
  }
}
```

so I'd like to output the index numbers 0 and 1 in a for loop. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig for loop and array with key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299202/twig-for-loop-and-array-with-key)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [The loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) as example:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ loop.index }} - {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

> loop.index    The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
>
> loop.index0   The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @BrendanJackson are you sure have accepted the correct answer at your question? I understand the correct answer was the `loop.index0`. Obviously is not a problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Just foreach through your main array, and specify you want the index:

```
foreach($array as $index=>$arr) { ...
```

$index will now give you what you need.

Or via TWIG:

```
{% for key,value in array_path %}
    Key : {{ key }}
    Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't think this is how twig does it.

Comment: Its just a regular php array don't forget (based on the var_dump you showed as an example) - try it, you may be pleasantly surprised.   -- I have updated my answer to show how to access via twigs templating

Comment: This should be the the accepted answer. While Matteos version will work in MOST times, it will not give the correct results for arrays with holes in them.

Comment: I agree with @EmanuelOster, this answer is more solid. In my case, I had a multidimensional array that for some reason loop.index0 was reseted to 0 in each group. Using key solved my problem. Thanks.