# How to get keyname of array in the view of twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig, array-key

Im coding in twig to visualize values that I get from php and I want that the keyname of array appear above the values.

```
{% if user.address %}
        <tr>
            {% for address in user.address %}
                {% for parts in address %}
                    <td width="25%">
                        {{ parts }}
                    </td>  
                {%endfor%}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>              
{% endif %}
```

In the part of under  `{% for address in user.address %}` I want put ( `{{address.key}}` or the real sentence that is necessary to get keyname of array )

The array is like:

```
  -address : array:4 [▼
    "Door" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "225"
    ]
    "Street" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Pinky street"
    ]
    "District" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "District north"
    ]
    "City" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "New York"
    ]
  ]
```

Edit:

Ty for the help the result is :

```
{% if user.address %}
        <tr>
           {% for key, address in user.address %}
                    <td width="25%">
                        {{ key }}
                    </td>
                {%endfor%}
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           {% for address in user.address %}
                {% for parts in address %}
                    <td width="25%">
                        {{ parts }}
                    </td>  
                    {%endfor%}
           {%endfor%}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig for loop and array with key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299202/twig-for-loop-and-array-with-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can  try this:

```
{% for key, address in user.address %}
```

In this way you have the key and the value

Comment: on what part of code? In first for or in the second for?

Comment: It depends, wher you want to get the key, I think that you need It into the first for, try and let me know please @segoitz

Comment: okay I implement code This is the result:

{% if user.address %}
        <tr>
           {% for key, address in user.address %}
                    <td width="25%">
                        {{ key }}
                    </td>
                {%endfor%}
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           {% for address in user.address %}
                {% for parts in address %}
                    <td width="25%">
                        {{ parts }}
                    </td>  
                    {%endfor%}
                {%endfor%}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
{% for key, user in users %}
    <li>{{ key }}: {{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

and here documentation [Iterating over Keys and Values](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values)